# Pytest unit testing getting a Can't instantiate abstract class error

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm currently testing this code using pytest from Storm_Centre.py

```
class Storm_Centre:
    def __init__(self):
        self.storm_list = []
        
    def already_exists(self, name) -> bool:
        for storm in self.storm_list:
            if storm.name == name:
                return True
        return False
```

this code uses code from Storm.py

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Storm(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name, wind_speed):
        self.name = name
        self.wind_speed = wind_speed
        super().__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def calculate_classification(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_advice(self):
        pass
```

I'm testing the code in test_storm.py using the following code:

```
import pytest
from Storm import Storm
from Storm_Centre import Storm_Centre

def test_already_exists():
    s1 = Storm('Jeff', 10)
    c1 = Storm_Centre()
    c1.storm_list.append(s1)
    assert(c1.already_exists('Jeff') == True)
    assert(c1.already_exists('Dave') == False)
```

When running the test I get a "Can't instantiate abstract class" error. If anyone could help solve this error it would be much appreciated. thank you!

Comment: You can't instantiate an abstract class, _it's abstract_.

Answer (score 2):

The point of creating an Abstract Class is that it's a class that you never instantiate. Instead, you have to implement a non-abstract subclass of it, which implements the two abstract methods, and then that's what you instantiate.

When you're writing the unit tests for `Storm_Centre` and the abstract `Storm` class itself, you'll need to define a non-abstract test sub class, something like this:

```
import pytest
from storm import Storm
from storm_centre import Storm_Centre

class TestStorm(Storm):
    def calculate_classification(self):
        return 4.2
    def get_advice(self):
        return "don't panic"

def test_already_exists():
    s1 = TestStorm('Jeff', 10)
    c1 = Storm_Centre()
    c1.storm_list.append(s1)
    assert(c1.already_exists('Jeff') == True)
    assert(c1.already_exists('Dave') == False)
```

EDIT: removed the unnecessary `__init__` method.

PS: you can use @chepner's idea to make this even smaller:

```
class TestStorm(Storm):
    pass
TestStorm.__abstractmethods__ = frozenset()
```

PPS: the typical Python filename convention is to use lowercase: class `Storm` is normally defined in file `storm.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract base classes are fairly easy to "subvert" for testing purposes.

```
>>> Storm.__abstractmethods__
frozenset({'calculate_classification', 'get_advice'})
>>> Storm("Jeff", 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Storm with abstract methods calculate_classification, get_advice
>>> Storm.__abstractmethods__ = frozenset()
>>> Storm("Jeff", 10)
<__main__.Storm object at 0x1011d0f50>
```

So to avoid the need to define a concrete subclass to instantiate, you can simply set the `__abstractmethods__` attribute to an empty list, set, etc, and the attempt to instantiate it will succeed (because it no longer reports any methods that must be overriden first).

Comment: I can see this would work, but it seems unsafe to me: you're monkey patching the abstract class in a global way, so if you have a bug where a piece of code in your code base tries to instantiate it, but your test suite only exercises that piece of code while the monkey patching is in effect, your unit testing will fail to find that bug, even if you hit 100% coverage.

Comment: I half agree: anything monkey patched, while temporary if you do it correctly, is global. That's what monkey patching it: just for the duration of a test (ideally), change something globally. In this case, we globally make `Storm` non abstract for the duration of a test. But your point stands, done with `unittest.mock.patch` as a context manager, we could make the change as short-lived as possible and thus not have unintended consequences, and minimize the chances of hiding a bug somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of cases where you are working with an instance of `Storm` in isolation, not in a larger context. If you can't control how the code-under-test uses `Storm`, then an explicit concrete subclass is better. (I did omit from the answer that you would probably use something like `unittest.mock.patch` to temporarily erase the list as well.)

Comment: Yeah, I might be tempted to do this: `with patch('Storm.Storm.__abstractmethods__', frozenset()): s = Storm('Jeff', 10)` but not much more. I only use monkey patching if I really have to.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's worth an upvote. I'm not sure why I didn't do so earlier.

Comment: I mostly posted this to point out that the entire ABC mechanism is more a strong warning against, rather than a prohibition on, instantiation.

Comment: Yeah, the Python ABC thing is weird. I've never actually used it in real code.